# dojo combo box drop down to be populated after n characters

Tags: combobox, dojo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Want to create a combobox in dojo where the dropdown menu and autocompletion kicks in only after the user inputs 4 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154281/want-to-create-a-combobox-in-dojo-where-the-dropdown-menu-and-autocompletion-kic)

Am creating a combox box and populating it from an item file store.i need the drop down to be populated only after entering 4 characters, could you guide please. Am pretty new to dojo. i got a sugestion on extending dojo methods,but i have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = new dijit.form.ComboBox({
                                   autoComplete: false.
                                   intermediateChanges: true,
                                   onChange: function(value) {
                                                            if(value.length < 4) {
                                                              this.autoComplete = false;
                                                            } else {
                                                              this.autoComplete = true;
                                                            }
                                   }
                                   },  srcNode);
```

or something like that

Comment: itried this and this does not work. Am actually using a item file store to populate the combobox, so i guess autocomplete will be false.