# dijit filteringSelect with min length

Tags: dojo

I can't seem to find a way to require the filtering select input to be of a certain length. I've tried like this:

```
new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    'name': 'bla',
    'store': jsonRestStore,
    'searchAttr': "name",
    'pattern': '.{3,}',
    'regExp': '.{3,}'
});
```

but it doesn't change a thing.  I want the filtering select to only query the store, if at least 3 characters have been entered. Can't be that exotic a requirement, can it? There are thousands of items behind that store, so querying that with just 1 or 2 characters is slow.

Comment: Just an idea.  Maybe you could add an event handler for `onChange`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a bit more searching and found [this post](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/FilteringSelect-delay-td3202213.html) on the dojo mailing list.  To summarize, there is no way to native support in the FilteringSelect for it, but it is extremely easy to implement.

```
// custom min input character count to trigger search
minKeyCount: 3,

// override search method, count the input length
_startSearch: function (/*String*/key) {
    if (!key || key.length < this.minKeyCount) {
    this.closeDropDown();
    return;
    }
    this.inherited(arguments);
}
```

Also in the  [API Docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/FilteringSelect), there is a `searchDelay` attribute, which could be helpful in minimizes the number of queries.

```
searchDelay 
Delay in milliseconds between when user types something and we start searching based on that value
```

Comment: Didn't see that there. Could be an ok workaround, in case my question doesn't go anywhere, so thanks.

Comment: Nice solution.  If you change "this.inherited(arguments)" to "this.inherited('_startSearch', arguments)" then you can just past what you wrote into the FilteringSelect without needing to make a new widget.

Comment: small addition: I omitted the `!key` condition, because in our dojo 1.6 application it prevented the dropdown to open at arrow-down / click on the triangle-thingy